# Latest one video uploaded in youtube channel

Tags: api, video, youtube, youtube-channels

I need to show the thumbnail of the latest video on my youtube channel on my website and add a link to that video. While using the API parameter date it's showing the first video in that channel. Instead of that, I need the last published video details how to solve this

This is what I used as I require only one last video

*https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=[key]&channelId=[channel-id]&part=snippet,id&order=relevance&maxResults=1*

Answer (score 0):

**(option 1)**

You could try replacing `order=relevance` with `order=date`

**try:**

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=[key]&channelId=[channel-id]&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=1

**(option 2)**

You could also try using `publishedAfter` command (which takes a *year-month-day* format). 
Example: `publishedAfter=2019-03-25T00:00:00Z` (because yesterday was March 25th).

**try:**

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=[key]&channelId=[channel-id]&part=snippet,id&publishedAfter=2019-03-25T00:00:00Z&order=date&maxResults=1

**(option 3)**

Use your programming language to fetch / read the HTML source-code of the channel's `uploads` page. The first thumbnail listed after `gridVideoRenderer` is the latest, along with relevant URL.

Example steps:

1) Go to user's uploads page and use "view source" option to see the HTML text (source code).
This text is what your programming language should show you when you **http request** the link of the channel's uploads.

https://www.youtube.com/user/MARVEL/videos

2) After acquiring (or viewing) the source code

- From there find position of the word `gridVideoRenderer`.
- Then starting after position, now find the first occurence of word `"url":"`.
- That is the URL. Extract manually by hand or write code to do it automatically.
  PS: Replace any unicode in the link, like `\u0026` with `&`.

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QuP7V2gKgPI/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEZCPYBEIoBSFXyq4qpAwsIARUAAIhCGAFwAQ==&rs=AOn4CLDBeSfAIiCdLDKtA8h2G-AZqk-xhQ

Comment: Option 1- Tried all the possible values for the order parameter. 
Option 2- this will return the first video after that specified date. If we upload new videos that won't be available. I need to dynamically fetch the most recent video and display the thumbnail.
I searched for so many options and got the info that youtube temporarily stopped this functionality  see this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129264189

Comment: What's your actual programming language for this task? If it's JavaScript then you cannot access the source code text since its a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried "option 1" with my own Key, and got the correct response as far as which "video" from the "Channel" - NO THUMBNAILs, just references to it/them, code follows:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "EymHvUd1w4o13UcSUT0C9YINu3o",
  "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
  "regionCode": "US",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 181,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "23QGL4Y9Du8EXMntX5ZNdr1F7_k",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "RRQjUvoSuKU"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2022-11-13T15:09:07Z",
        "channelId": "UCbhMYK2QQXgHjgnMN3zegRQ",
        "title": "All Things Closely",
        "description": "Luke 1:1-4.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RRQjUvoSuKU/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RRQjUvoSuKU/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RRQjUvoSuKU/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Restoration Church Homestead",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2022-11-13T15:09:07Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

THAT's all that showed on a browser page, no Thumbnails-just code, but could not figure out how to get any code in the string to PLAY that video ...
any ideas?
I would love to just have it as a LINK rather than any other scripts loaded on the server. I'm missing something, probably simple I bet, to get the returned video related to the data to play.